# How to convert all 'object' values in dataset to float or int in a single command?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a train dataset which has 43 attributes. Each of the attributes have some tuple values as objects (as in strings with certain characters).
Now, I'm trying to scale the values using a scaler, but it gives the following error:

```
 could not convert string to float: '?'
```

Now, I don't know how to convert objects to int or float in a single command and converting it for each of the 43 attributes one by one is a bit tedious.

So I want to know how to do it for the complete dataset with a single command.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `convert` function which tries to parse the string as a float.
If it cannot, it tries to parse it as a int, and if it still cannot, assigns the value 0 (you can change the default value is the string is not a int or a float to something else)

```
l = []

def convert(str):
    x = 0
    try:
        x = int(str)
    except:
        try:
            x = float(str)
        except:
            pass
    l.append(x)

for i in ['1','2','3','?','4.5']:
    convert(i)
print(l)
#[1, 2, 3, 0, 4.5]
```

Comment: I am not using a list...I am using a series

Comment: That was just for an example, you can convert your series to a list, or loop through your series accordingly